# Adding function to my class

Tags: c#, list, generics

I have a class, and there is a List in this class, I want to add a `Where` function to my class that calls the `Where` function of the List, Something like this:

```
 public class MyClass<T> where T : class
 {    
    public Func<T, IEnumerable<T>>  Where{ get; set; }
    public List<T> mylist = new List<T>();
    public MyClass()
    {
         Where = mylist.Where;
    }
 }
```

I'm getting the Error:

```
No overload for 'Where' matches delegate 'Func<T, IEnumerable<T>>
```

Comment: Can you please explain how it is that you intend to use your `Where` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your delegate has the wrong type, it should be:

```
public Func<Func<T, bool>, IEnumerable<T>> Where { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

As per [IEnumerable on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx) there is `IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(Func<TSource, Boolean>)` and `IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(Func<TSource, Int32, Boolean>)`.

These are castable to `Func<Func<TSource, Boolean>, IEnumerable<TSource>>` and `Func<Func<TSource, Int32, Boolean>, IEnumerable<TSource>>` respectably.

Neither match the type declared for your property "Where", which is `Func<T, IEnumerable<T>>`, and that is why the compiler tells you `No overload for 'Where' matches delegate 'Func<T, IEnumerable<T>>`.

You need to choose an appropriate delegate type.

Answer (score 0):

`List<T>` provides no `Where`-Function. `Where` is an extension function for enumerables, see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb549418(v=vs.100).aspx). See the other answers how you can correct your property to match the type of the extension function.

Of course I have no idea what you want to achive, but if you want a list class with an assignable filter, you can use something like this:

```
public class MyClass<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : class {

    public Func<T, bool> Filter { get; set; }
         = T => true; // default: no filter

    public List<T> mylist = new List<T>();

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        => mylist.Where(Filter).GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        => mylist.Where(Filter).GetEnumerator();
}
```